# JSON, jq, merged text + variable + bash variable, arguments

Tags: json, bash, variables, jq, command-line-arguments

I have similar file/data:

```
$ echo "[{\"my_var1\":\"valueA\", \"my_var2\": \"valueB\"}]"
{"my_var1":"valueA", "my_var2": "valueB"}]
```

in my code I need to get value of "my_var2", easy:

```
$ echo "[{\"my_var1\":\"valueA\", \"my_var2\": \"valueB\"}]" | \
jq -r '.[] .my_var2'

# correct result:
valueB
```

... but ... I need to use bash variable to specify which variable I would like to get:

I can't specify "my_var2", I have to use only "var2"

```
$ PART="var2"
$ echo "[{\"my_var1\":\"valueA\", \"my_var2\": \"valueB\"}]" | \
jq -r --arg JSONPART ${PART} '.[] .my_[$JSONPART]'
```

expected result:

```
valueB
```

Answer (score 2):

The jq filter `.xyz` can be rewritten as `.["xyz"]`. Thus:

```
$ PART='var2'
$ echo '[{"my_var1":"valueA", "my_var2": "valueB"}]' | \
jq -r --arg JSONPART "$PART" '.[]["my_" + $JSONPART]'
valueB
```

(Don't forget to properly quote your shell parameters when expanding!)

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
$ PART="var2"
$ echo "[{\"my_var1\":\"valueA\", \"my_var2\": \"valueB\"}]" | \
jq -r ".[] .my_$PART"
```

Comment: This will only work for the most simple of cases, but will fail as soon as the `PART` variable contains spaces or quotes

Comment: Well it's a simple case. Do you see any spaces or quotes in `PART="var2"`